# Nuxt Application redirect to auth page and return to dashboard by refresh page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

i used Nuxt.js
and i used auth Nuxt.js .
after login to dashboard page by refresh goto auth and return to dashboard page.
by routing all is ok but by refresh not correct!

```
auth: {
        cookie: {
            prefix: 'auth.',
            options: {
                maxAge: '3600'
            }
        },
        redirect: {
            login: '/auth/login',
            logout: '/auth/login',
            callback: false,
            home: false
        },

        strategies: {
            local: {
                login: { url: '/api/auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
                logout: { url: '/api/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
                user: { url: '/api/auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'user' }
            },
            // token_type: '',
        }
    },
```

and in post/_slug.vue
by refresh return 404 error !

```
mode: universal
ssr : true
```

Comment: its all ok in localhost but in sharing host by refresh 404 !